# Bulk editing files through command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a list of about 500 folders.  Inside each of those folders is a `functions.php` file.

I need to search every `functions.php` file for the following text:

```
function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish()
```

I need to replace any line that has the above text with this:

```
function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish() { $uri = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); if(is_admin() || substr_count($uri, "wp-admin") > 0 || substr_count($uri, "wp-login") > 0 ) { /* */ } else { $l = 'mydomain.com'; $f = dirname(__file__) . "/footer.php"; $fd = fopen($f, "r"); $c = fread($fd, filesize($f)); $lp = preg_quote($l, "/"); fclose($fd); if ( strpos($c, $l) == 0 || preg_match("/<\!--(.*" . $lp . ".*)-->/si", $c) || preg_match("/<\?php([^\?]+[^>]+" . $lp . ".*)\?>/si", $c) ) { wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; } } } wp_initialize_the_theme_finish();
```

NOTE:  I need to replace the entire line with my new line, not just the beginning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sed will be able to do that for you, use `-i` (in-place) flag

Comment: I was actually able to do that on one file.  I guess the part that I'm not understanding is how to search all of the functions.php files in all folders and replace everything at once...

Comment: i answered how you find all the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty detailed [article](http://rushi.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/find-replace-across-multiple-files-in-linux/) written on it. Seems to relate to your question very well. Essentially the command is:

```
find . -name "*/function.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Where foo is :

```
 function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish().+\n
```

and bar is:

```
function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish() { $uri = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); if(is_admin() || substr_count($uri, "wp-admin") > 0 || substr_count($uri, "wp-login") > 0 ) { /* */ } else { $l = 'mydomain.com'; $f = dirname(__file__) . "/footer.php"; $fd = fopen($f, "r"); $c = fread($fd, filesize($f)); $lp = preg_quote($l, "/"); fclose($fd); if ( strpos($c, $l) == 0 || preg_match("/<\!--(.*" . $lp . ".*)-->/si", $c) || preg_match("/<\?php([^\?]+[^>]+" . $lp . ".*)\?>/si", $c) ) { wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; } } } wp_initialize_the_theme_finish();
```

Use the [following rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script) to escape special characters in foo and bar:
In a nutshell, for sed:

1. Write the regex between single quotes.
2. Use '\'' to search for asingle quote.
3. Put a backslash before $.*/[]^ and only those characters.

Comment: I keep getting this error when trying that: `sed: -e expression #1, char 239: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: Just tried that and got this error:  `sed: -e expression #1, char 239: unknown option to s`

Comment: `\Q` and `\E` is supported in `perl` not in `sed`

Comment: Sorry about that. my mistake. For sed you need to use the following rules:In a nutshell, for sed:

**Write the regex between single quotes.
Use '\'' to search for a single quote.
Put a backslash before $.*/[\]^ and only those characters.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` command, to search for all the relevant files, then use `sed -i` to update the files

Answer (score 0):

Since search and replace strings are reasonably long, first store them in variables.

Then try using `find` along with `sed` using `-exec` option

```
#!/bin/bash

search='^.*function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish().*$'
replace='function wp_initialize_the_theme_finish() { $uri = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); if(is_admin() || substr_count($uri, "wp-admin") > 0 || substr_count($uri, "wp-login") > 0 ) { /* */ } else { $l = "mydomain.com"; $f = dirname(__file__) . "/footer.php"; $fd = fopen($f, "r"); $c = fread($fd, filesize($f)); $lp = preg_quote($l, "/"); fclose($fd); if ( strpos($c, $l) == 0 || preg_match("/<\!--(.*" . $lp . ".*)-->/si", $c) || preg_match("/<\?php([^\?]+[^>]+" . $lp . ".*)\?>/si", $c) ) { wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; } } } wp_initialize_the_theme_finish();'

find -type f -name 'function.php' -exec sed -i "s/${search}/${replace}/g" {} \;
```

---

Other alternative using `xargs`

```
find -type f -name 'function.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/${search}/${replace}/g"
```